# Django Framework ManyToManyField. How can i get a specific value in my index list page

Tags: python, django, manytomanyfield

I have problem with Django Framework, one blog post may have several tags, how can i get tags value of post list in my index page? I only can get one post's tag in a post detail page.

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class Tag(models.Model):
    tag_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.tag_name


class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
    publish_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py:

```
def home(request):
posts = Article.objects.all().order_by('-publish_time')
paginator = Paginator(posts, 4)
page = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    post_list = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    post_list = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    post_list = paginator.paginator(paginator.num_pages)
return render(request, 'home.html', {'post_list': post_list})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In template you can get all article's tags:

```
{% for post in post_list %}
    {% for tag in post.tag.all %}
        Use your tags here
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
tag_list = Tag.objects.filter(article__in=post_list)
```

`tag_list` is all tags, that posts in `post_list` have.

Or

```
tag_list = Tag.objects.filter(article__in=posts)
```

`tag_list` is all tags, that posts in `posts` have.